# MS Sql order by numeric parts of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to order my query by numeric parts.

I have a lot of rows looks like:

```
'ABCD.1234.567'
'ABCD.1234-2345'
'ABCD.1234.1213.1'
```

So, I want firs order by first numeric part, then by second and then by therd.
Like this:

```
'ABCD.1234.567'
'ABCD.1234.1213.1'
'ABCD.1234-2345'
```

How can I do this?

**UPD:** I have tried to use PATINDEX function in order by, but can figure out how to do that for all numbers.

```
order by s.product, (case when Patindex('% ,.,-%', s.product)=0 then 0
                        else Cast(SUBSTRING(s.product, Patindex('%[0-9]%', s.product), len(s.product)) as int) end)
```

Comment: @PeterB I'v tried to use pathindex function, you can se this in UPD

Comment: Do the strings strictly follow the format 4 characters followed by a special character followed by 4 numbers followed by another special characters then 4 numeric agaim?

Comment: Are the separators always . and -?

Comment: What version of SQL Server too?

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno Now, there coud me any characters betwen separators, max 3 groups, delimetrs could be - and .

Comment: @gbn SQL 2008R2

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string split function

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Name varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
('ABCD.1234.567'),
('ABCD.1234-2345'),
('ABCD.1234.1213.1')
```

Your query would be

```
SELECT *
FROM @SampleData sd
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST(t.Value AS int) AS Part1
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString](replace(sd.Name,'-', '.'),'.') t
    WHERE t.Pos = 2
) p1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST(t.Value AS int) AS Part2
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString](replace(sd.Name,'-', '.'),'.') t
    WHERE t.Pos = 3
) p2
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST(t.Value AS int) AS Part3
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString](replace(sd.Name,'-', '.'),'.') t
    WHERE t.Pos = 4
) p3
ORDER BY p1.[Part1], p2.[Part2], p3.Part3
```

And string split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] (@Text varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
   Select Pos = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
        ,Value = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
   From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@Text,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
   Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Result:

```
Name              Part1  Part2  Part3
---------------------------------------
ABCD.1234.567     1234   567    NULL
ABCD.1234.1213.1  1234   1213   1
ABCD.1234-2345    1234   2345   NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

For 4 groups or less, PARSENAME makes a great string split function

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (foo varchar(100));
INSERT @foo
VALUES
('ABCD.1234.567'),
('ABCD.1234-2345'),
('ABCD.1234.1213.1')

SELECT
    Y.foo
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        Element1 = REVERSE(PARSENAME(X.ProcessedFoo, 1)),
        Element2 = REVERSE(PARSENAME(X.ProcessedFoo, 2)),
        Element3 = REVERSE(PARSENAME(X.ProcessedFoo, 3)),
        Element4 = REVERSE(PARSENAME(X.ProcessedFoo, 4)),
        X.foo
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            foo, 
            ProcessedFoo = REVERSE(REPLACE(foo, '-', '.'))
        FROM @foo 
        ) X
    ) Y
ORDER BY
    Y.Element1, 
    CAST(Y.Element2 AS int), 
    CAST(Y.Element3 AS int), 
    CAST(Y.Element4 AS int);
```